# Merge two list object in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to merge two lists but what I'm getting is an error,
I've searched a lot on the internet but can't find the solution to my problem.
Please help me. Thank you.

this is the error in the for loop

```
 for (var i = 0; i < titleList.length; i++) {
    titleList[i]['src'] = thumbnail[i]['1'];
  }
```

```
Unhandled exception:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
#0      main
bin\dart_webscrape2.dart:34
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
#2      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

What I tried is

```
import 'package:web_scraper/web_scraper.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async {
  final webScraper = WebScraper('https://w22.holymanga.net');

  // Response of getElement is always List<Map<String, dynamic>>
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> titleLink;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> thumbnails;

  // Loads web page and downloads into local state of library
  if (await webScraper.loadWebPage('/genre/full-color/page-2/')) {
    // getElement takes the address of html tag/element and attributes you want to scrape from website
    // it will return the attributes in the same order passed
    titleLink = webScraper
        .getElement('div.comics-grid > div.entry > a.thumb', ['title', 'href']);
    thumbnails = webScraper
        .getElement('div.comics-grid > div.entry > a.thumb > img', ['src']);
  }

  var titleList = [];
  var thumbnail = [];

  titleLink.forEach((element) {
    final title = element['attributes']['href'];
    titleList.add('$title');
  });

  thumbnails.forEach((element) {
    final thumb = element['attributes'];
    thumbnail.add('$thumb');
  });

 
  for (var i = 0; i < titleList.length; i++) {
    titleList[i]['src'] = thumbnail[i]['1'];
  }
}
```

Please help me.
thank you

Comment: your `thumbnail` and `titleList` are both array of strings. `titleList[i]['src'] = thumbnail[i]['1']` this can't be done on string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
titleLink.forEach((element) {
    final title = element['attributes']['href'];
    titleList.add('$title'); // You're adding a string to the list
  });

for (var i = 0; i < titleList.length; i++) {
    titleList[i]['src'] = thumbnail[i]['1']; // But you're trying to access it as if it was a map
  }
```

If `['attributes']['href']` is map then instead of `titleList.add('$title')` do `titleList.add(title)`